# Android Image Picker and Cropper

Tags: android, android-camera, crop

I am working on android application in which i want to take image from Gallery and Camera and after that i want to apply crop intent. I found that image URI concept is changed in 4.0 later api. Is there any source code which works for every api for Image picking and cropping. I will be very thankful for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> i want to apply crop intent

[Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

> I found that image URI concept is changed in 4.0 later api

I have no idea what you mean by that.

> Is there any source code which works for every api for Image picking and cropping

Probably not, as "every api" would have to go back to 2008's Android 1.0, and few developers bother creating libraries for such old versions of Android.

The Android Arsenal has [a category of image cropping libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), some of which may meet your requirements.

Comment: actually i want a tutorial or a sample code which will works for image cropping. I didn't find any sample code or library which works for both 4.0 API and Kitkat api.

Comment: @muhammadusmankhan: "actually i want a tutorial or a sample code which will works for image cropping" -- the libraries listed at the Android Arsenal category that I linked to appear to all be open source. Some have links to blog posts that offer "tutorials", and some have samples for using their libraries. "I didn't find any sample code or library which works for both 4.0 API and Kitkat api" -- I do not know what you consider "4.0 API" and "Kitkat api" to be.