# Cropping library not working on Nexus S

Tags: android, android-camera, nexus-s

I am working on an Android application in which I am doing image cropping. I have used the following line of code which is working for Gallery and Camera. I have tested it on LG- Nexus and MicroMax Mobile having API 4.2, it is working fine on both of them but not for Samsung Nexus - S. On Cropping activity when I press OK button nothing happens. It also don't give any error.

```
public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){
        //call the standard crop action intent 
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri of image
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 512);

        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
    }
```

Comment: The comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463415/android-crop-error-with-samsung-devices seems to answer your question.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: FWIW, I have pointed out to the OP on [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582109/115145) separate [occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27581070/115145) that [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp thanks for your response. But there is no answer on that link which will gives me a solution for my problem. Can u please give me any other information for my problem. It should be appreciated.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you read it again and carefully here, i haven't mentioned any crop intent. I have used only the object name for "crop intent". If you have an information related to my question then kindly share it here. This is the third time where i received no informative comment from you. Thanks.

Comment: "i haven't mentioned any crop intent" -- yes, you have. It is the first line of `cropCapturedImage()` method that you have in your question. [`com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not part of the Android SDK](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), and not all Android devices will support it, let alone your particular mix of extras.